# Encryption in response payload from GET query

Tags: parsing, encryption, python-requests, rsa, private-key

i'm trying to get data of "Export potential" platinum for South Africa from

https://exportpotential.intracen.org/en/markets/gap-chart?fromMarker=i&exporter=710&whatMarker=k&what=711019&toMarker=j

with Python requests.

I need the following data for each country.

[Example data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EREcK.jpg)

I think that I can get data from GET response, but if I explore Network tab in browser debugger, I see GET-request

Request URL: https://exportpotential.intracen.org/api/epis/targeted/from/product/to/exporter/marker/k/id/711019

Unfortunantly, the response is encrypted.

> 6iCAiWaW1XZJbKsS5qQ/xi/BAjjuW+be41Kv9tsJK8QuAo076JqB45lqPYR76rLsJjmRXBnrxExBXs5tJSfCeYpAPOrWE1raR+UyDJtujAgezfZV22PH16UI+RhwvBA26hcd8FvxLCCA1/DPDNNT6xKGVXi0Ykm7ih2mFcR3N5mq...

I am assuming it is encrypted with RSA algorithm because it looks like the following:

https://karatejb.blogspot.com/2020/02/aspnet-core-encrypt-and-decrypt-request.html

[It looks like the encrypted message in my case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NOjY.png)

Probably I can use private-key and decrypt this data, but I don't know where find this key and I'm not sure about the algorithm. The question is not related to ITC site only because I met similar encrypted responces from many other sites.

There are two questions:

1. How to decipher this data with Python?
2. Where can I find the private-key to decrypt it? For purposes of simplicity I am going to use this facility: [https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=RSA_Decrypt('-----BEGIN%20RSA%20PRIVATE%20KEY-----','','RSA-OAEP','SHA-1')](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=RSA_Decrypt(%27-----BEGIN%20RSA%20PRIVATE%20KEY-----%27,%27%27,%27RSA-OAEP%27,%27SHA-1%27)).

Comment: The response just appears to be base64 encoded, it thus could be anything, not necessarily RSA. Whether or not it is encrypted you will have to obtain technical documentation from the data owner to understand how to decrypt it, and they may require you register.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, yes you are rigth, the first step is Base64.